# SNS: SMS not delivered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I using sns of aws to send sms, when I log cloudwatch i see:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "ac8d8d02-491d-58bf-ace8-xxxxxx",
        "timestamp": "2021-01-01 00:03:54.576"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "phoneCarrier": "Viettel",
        "mnc": 4,
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+843293xxxxx",
        "priceInUSD": 0.0525,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 452,
        "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone carrier",
        "dwellTimeMs": 361,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 2604
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

But in my phone, I don't get any message, How I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For several countries, senders are required to use a pre-registered alphabetic sender ID.

To request a sender ID from AWS Support, file a support request. Some countries require senders to meet specific requirements or abide by certain restrictions in order to obtain approval.

In these cases, AWS Support might contact you for additional information after you submit your sender ID request.

For further information about this, you can read [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html).

Comment: Good catch! The above applies to **Vietnam**, which the OP appears to be using.